# How to tell what is preventing Linux shutdown?

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, shutdown

I built a Linux workstation that won't shut down, suspend or sleep properly, and I posted [a detailed question about it on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/758381/kubuntu-not-shutting-down). I have since tried many different "solutions" but the problem remains unsolved (and yes, I have all the latest updates and graphics drivers).

When I attempt to shut it down, the screen immediately goes black so I have no way to tell what is causing it to hang.  Using `journalctl` when it boots back up hasn't helped (but that may partly be due to my own ignorance).  It often takes 5 or more attempts to reboot before it resumes normal behavior, and during that period the screen sometimes goes black after I have logged in.  Once it has resumed normal behavior, it is stable and everything operates as expected, even for long periods, until I try to shut it down again.

How can I tell what applications or processes are causing it to hang, and/or what applications or processes cause the black screen after login?

Comment: Stack Exchange rules allow you to post a question on any *sister* site, but not multiple sites (ie. not SE *Unix & Linux* and SE AskUbuntu). Since you're using 23.04 and 6.2 kernel that is soon to go EOL (*warning notices of this recently went out, eg.* https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/12/15/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reaches-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/) I'd not spend time on it until you've tried the 6.5 kernel you'll be on very soon.

Comment: After the system comes up again, the terminal command `sudo journalctl   b -1 -ex` will show the system logs leading up to the crash/shutdown. You can look at other shutdowns by varying the `-b -1` option. If nothing stands out, suspect overheating or sudden power outage. Do `sudo journalctl  --list-boots`, read `man journalctl`. For more `journalctl` help, see my AskUbuntu profile (click on my username).

Comment: OK, thanks to you both.  I have already upgraded to 23.10 and the problem persists (I updated my other question just now). @waltinator thanks for the pointers re `journalctl`.